# What does "inclusive" mean here: "Age Pension age increased to 66 years and 6 months for people born from 1 July 1955 to 31 December 1956, inclusive."

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

This sentence is from Australian social security web site [Pension](https://www.servicesaustralia.gov.au/who-can-get-age-pension?context=22526)

**On 1 July 2021, Age Pension age increased to 66 years and 6 months for people born from 1 July 1955 to 31 December 1956, inclusive.**

What does "inclusive" mean here? Does it mean "The dates 1 July and 31 December are also included."?

Comment: Yes, that is what 'inclusive' means when discussing a range of dates, and you could have found that out using a [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inclusive).

Comment: I did look it up, but could not quite make sure that the word "inclusive" refers to only the date preceeding it, or does it refer to both dates.

Comment: "including the **first and last** date or number stated" - Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: Yes, you are right. I apparently did not read the explanation carefully. I used Collins Dictionary and it says the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are correct. `Inclusive` here means that the numbers user for the range, are also included in the range.

For example:
*between 1 and 10* means

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

but *between 1 and 10 inclusive* means

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Your first example is incorrect.  Between 1 and 10 is ambiguous as to whether in includes the 1 and the 10.  You imply that it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what it means.

With dates especially, using "from" and "to" often results in a perceived [ambiguity about the bounds](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), which "inclusive" addresses.